# Adding An array of Objects to a subdocument using mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

I was adding an array of objects as a subdocument in **mongoDB** using **mongoose**. I am not able to iterate through the array to save it.

Below is the request data:

```
{"order" : 
  [{
    "price": "50",
    "quantity" : "3",
    "vegId": "60c8b471e12c801e54b7ee59",
    "vegName": "Tomato"
  },
  {
    "price": "50",
    "quantity" : "3",
    "vegId": "60c8b471e12c841e54b7ee59",
    "vegName": "Onion"
  }],
  "userId" : "60cb597f1edc34385060c288",
  "orderTotal":"350",
  "createdOn" : "21-6-2021"
}
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
exports.confirmOrder = (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.body);
    // res.status(201).json({
    //     message: " Message Going"
    // })
    const orderData = req.body.order;
    console.log(orderData);


    const order = new Orders({
        userId: req.body.userId,
        orderTotal: req.body.orderTotal,
        vegetables: [{
            vegId: orderData[0].vegId,
            quantity: orderData[0].quantity,
            price: orderData[0].price,
            vegName: orderData[0].vegName
        }]
    });
    order.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Oder Confirmed"
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(501).json({
            message: " An Error has occured"
        })
    });
};
```

how can I iterate through the request data in vegetables.

Comment: just assign `vegetables: orderData`, no need to iterate loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate. Basically, you need to assign the vegetables data like below:

```
const data = {
    "order": [
        {
            "price": "50",
            "quantity": "3",
            "vegId": "60c8b471e12c801e54b7ee59",
            "vegName": "Tomato"
        },
        {
            "price": "50",
            "quantity": "3",
            "vegId": "60c8b471e12c841e54b7ee59",
            "vegName": "Onion"
        }
    ],
    "userId": "60cb597f1edc34385060c288",
    "orderTotal": "350",
    "createdOn": "21-6-2021"
}

    const order = new Orders({
        userId: req.body.userId,
        orderTotal: req.body.orderTotal,
        vegetables: data.order //Give your vegetables data here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**I came up with something like this:-**

```
exports.confirmOrder = (req, res, next) => { 
const orderData= req.body.order;
const data = [];
orderData.forEach((orders)=>{
    data.push({
        vegId:orders.vegId,
        quantity: orders.quantity,
        price: orders.price,
        vegName:orders.vegName
    });
});

const order = new Orders({
    userId: req.body.userId,
    orderTotal: req.body.orderTotal,
    vegetables: data
});
order.save().then(result =>{
    res.status(201).json({
        message: "Oder Confirmed"
    });
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(501).json({
        message:" An Error has occured"
    })
});
```

};